# Mips Programming sorting and giving result in ascending order and adding the values

Tags: assembly, mips

Write a MIPS program that performs the following:
• Prompt a user to enter N positive integers, (0< N ≤ 100). 
• Display the N integers in ascending order
• For each integer in the output list display also the sum of its digits

**I can't seem to get the program to stop when 0 is entered and add the sum of the digits entered.**

**My Solution**

```
.data 
array:  .space 40   
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a number: "  
spacee: .asciiz " " 
output: .asciiz "The numbers are: " 
.text 

main: 
 li $t1,10         #load 10 into $t1 
 la $a1,array      #load a pointer to array into $a1 

loop: 
 addi $t1,$t1,-1   #subtract 1 from $t1, save to $t1 
 li $v0,4          #load 4 into $v0 (print string) 
 la $a0,prompt     #load prompt text into $a 
 syscall           #display prompt 
 li $v0,5          #load 5 into $v0 (read integer) 
 syscall           #prompt for input 
 sw $v0,0($a1)     #store input int to array 
 addi $a1,$a1,4    #add 4 to $a1, save to $a1 
 bnez $t1,loop     #if $t1 isn't zero,goto loop 
 li $t1,9          #if $t1 is zero, load 9 into $t1 
 li $t2,9          #and load 9 into $t2 
 la $a1,array      #load array pointer into $a1 

loop1: 
 beqz $t2,here     #if $t2 is zero, goto here 
 addi $t2,$t2,-1   #subtract 1 from $t2, save to $t2 
 lw $t5,0($a1)     #load an input int into $t5 
 lw $t6,4($a1)     #load the next one into $t6 
 addi $a1,$a1,4    #add 4 to $a1, save to $a1 
 ble $t5,$t6,loop1 #if $t5 <= $t6, goto loop1 
 sw $t5,0($a1)     #else, store $t5 in $a1 
 sw $t6,-4($a1)     #and store $t6 in $a1-4 (swapping them) 
 bnez $t2,loop1    #if $t2 is not zero, to go loop1 

here: 
 la $a1,array      #load array into $a1 
 addi $t1,$t1,-1   #subtract 1 from $t1, save to $t1 
 add $t2,$t2,$t1   #add $t2 to $t1, save to $t2 
 bnez $t1,loop1    #if $t1 isn't zero, goto loop1 
 li $v0,4          #load 4 into $v0 (print string) 
 la $a0,output     #load 'the numbers are' into $a0 
 syscall           #display message to screen 
 la $a1,array      #load array pointer into $a1 
 li $t1,10         #load 10 into $t1 

loop2: 
 li $v0,1          #load 1 into $v0 (print int) 
 lw $a0,0($a1)     #load $a1 into $a0 
 syscall           #print first number to screen 
 li $v0,4          #load 4 into $v1 (print string) 
 la $a0,spacee     #load ' ' into $a0 
 syscall           #print ' ' to screen 
 addi $a1,$a1,4    #add 4 to $a1, save to $a1 
 addi $t1,$t1,-1   #subtract 1 from $t1, save to $t1 
 bnez $t1,loop2    #if $t1 isn't zero, goto loop2 



 li $v0,10              #exit 

 syscall
```

Comment: @Nicholas Riley: use of the `homework` tag is now discouraged, apparently - the fact that this is homework should instead be mentioned in the questions - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: whoops, I've been away for a while... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a branch that will branch to the two last lines of your code.

```
    beq $v0, $zero, quit   #this should be in the loop

quit:                      #this is your last two lines
    li $v0,10              #exit 
    syscall
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can you give some guidance?  Don't know where to start with that part.